# PayPal ipn missing POST data

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I used this code to catch the data about payment: https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/tree/master/php

Set `$this->use_sandbox` to `true`

When creating a button in PayPal sandbox business account I entered link to page with this code to go to when payment is successful

I set the same link in [Instant Payment Notification](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify) settings and enabled it.

When I pay with PayPal sandbox personal account and get returned to the link I set in success case in button and IPN, it says:

> Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'PaypalIPN' has no effect in /public_html/paypal_success.php on line 3

And:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Missing POST Data in
>   /public_html/PaypalIPN.php:72 Stack trace: #0
>   /public_html/paypal_success.php(7): PaypalIPN->verifyIPN() #1 {main}
>   thrown in /public_html/PaypalIPN.php on line 72

Error is the same as if I didn't go through paying process.

Why is POST data missing?

I'm confused whether 'Listener' URL equals to URL you get returned to when you make a payment (button success URL).

Comment: have you tried using the Paypal [IPN simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/)? I'm not sure it helps much but it's a start. I would say in general that Paypal is horrific and that you'd save yourself lots of time and stress by using something cleaner and sharper [such as Stripe](https://stripe.com/gb).

Comment: It's a shame I already started with PayPal. Or not because Stripe doesn't seem to be free. I abandoned that official code. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U88y-cyGaHM This is what I'm currently working with, IPN simulator works with it.

Comment: Or not... It receives POST data but I don't know how to use IPN simulator on this code. I suppose I need to edit code so that it would listen for sandbox instead of real PayPal but I don't know what to edit.

Comment: Err, Stripe is free, and charges a lower percentage than Paypal on transactions. What's your stress levels worth?

Comment: People are familiar with PP and trust it more I bet. Besides, I need a way to know when a person has made a payment programmatically just like the guy needed in the video tutorial. I bet there would be as much fuss anyway.

Comment: with respect, your comment is simply full of your own prejudice and unwillingness to explore alterior options. That's fine, I simply offer Stripe as a viable and comparative alternative option. Don't dismiss it simply through your own ignorance. I once was all over Paypal as you seem to be now, but after getting sick to the back teeth of the horrific coding style, the terrible developer interface and the frankly disgusting way that PP push all their valid tech queries on to Stack Overflow, I took some time to learn Stripe, and have never looked back. Saving me time and cheaper for my clients.